# Problem in redirecting output from wolframscript

Tags: scripting

I am having a very strange problem in scripting with wolframscript.

As a MWE I have a .wls which prints its command line argument. I launch several of these scripts with a bash script, each redirecting the output on a different file.
However, both instances of the script write on the same file!

I attach a screenshot, to show that there is no problem with the bash script I show that with echo rather than wolframscript the redirection works fine.[image]

Comment: Instead of a screenshot it would be better to use the `script` command to create a session log as a text file which you can then quote in your question.